# How to correct user input before validating/saving?

Tags: yii

There is a field for price in my form that will be saved in a decimal format into db.

Now if a user types commas '**,**' not points '**.**', how can I quietly replace it so that it will be saved correctly? eg instead of `12,34`, there will be saved `12.34`, not `12.00`

Comment: you might look at http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeNumberField-detail - the CHtml#activeNumberField

Comment: good hint, although this time my client wants to let the user input in whatever form and correct it by software if needed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would probably be easiest if you used a [`CFilterValidator`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFilterValidator) to convert the input from a string to a float value automatically when validation happens; the rest should take care of itself.

So your model would have

```
public function rules() {
    return array(
        array('price', 'filter', 'filter' => 'convertToFloat'),
    );
}
```

and the filtering function would be something like

```
function convertToFloat($value) {
    return floatval(trim(str_replace(',', '.', $value)));
}
```

You can also specify the filtering function as any valid [callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php), for example make it a model method and specify it as

```
'filter' => array($this, 'convertToFloat')
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked when I put the function into the model and used `'filter' => array($this, 'convertToFloat')`. I didn't find yet where to put teh convertToFloat function so that it works in every model.

Comment: @zuups.com: You could just drop it inside `index.php`. You didn't hear it from me, but it works.

Comment: @zuups.com you could write the `convertToFloat` function in a parent ActiveRecord class, but it's better to write a separate validator class as described here: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/168/create-your-own-validation-rule/#hh1